# Is there a way to set Parameters in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-shell

I have a LOAD_CSV cypher script that creates and sets properties for nodes and edges.

I want to add a parameter at run time (i.e. when I do `cat mycypher.cql | cypher-shell -u xxxx -p xxx`) so that a key property gets set on nodes -- like so:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM $MY_CSV AS row
MERGE (a:abcLabel {abcId: toInteger(row.abc_id), extraProp: $EXTRA_PROPERTY})
ON CREATE SET
    abc.name = row.abc_name
MERGE (b:bcdLabel {bcdId: toInteger(row.bcd_id), extraProp: $EXTRA_PROPERTY})
ON CREATE SET
    etc ....
```

Now, know that I can't use shell-like params, but is there a way to set $EXTRA_PROPERTY and $MY_FILE so that I can rerun the cql against a separate data set and ensure that a subsequent `MATCH (:abcProperty {extraLabel: "xyz"})` will return nodes that were given the "xyz" property?

In principle this would be completely automated and templated so I will never do a manual load.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Upcoming version 1.2 of `cypher-shell` will support the command line option `--param`, which would allow you to specify Cypher parameters.

*[Here](https://github.com/neo4j/cypher-shell/pull/164) is the merged pull request.*